# How can TortoiseSVN be installed from msiexec.exe command line and include command utilities?

Tags: installation, windows-installer, tortoise-svn

I need to create a command line that will install TortoiseSVN and include the Subversion command line utilities.

What options on the msiexec.exe command line would tell the installer to include the command set?

TortoiseSVN-1.9.3.27038-x64-svn-1.9.3.msi

Comment: Try running `TortoiseSVN-1.9.3.27038-x64-svn-1.9.3.msi /?` in a `cmd` shell.

Comment: @DavidPostill - Using `/?` brings up the Microsoft msiexec.exe help dialog box. While it does mention `Setting Public Properties`, it does not show what properties can be set nor what they mean.

Comment: SlikSVN has an INSTALLLEVEL property which can be used to ensure that svnserve.exe is installed. `msiexec /q /i Slik-Subversion-1.7.9-x64.msi /log "%TEMP%\slik-subversion-install.log INSTALLLEVEL=300`

Answer (score 1):

The following worked for me using TortoiseSVN 1.13.1:

```bat
Msiexec /i "TortoiseSVN.msi" /qn ADDLOCAL="F_OVL,DefaultFeature,MoreIcons,CLI,CrashReporter,UDiffAssoc,DictionaryENGB,DictionaryENUS"
```

- Where `TortoiseSVN.msi` is the specific installer. 
   To see all available properties use the following and delete any entry that has a lowercase letter (there may be false positives but it is better than anything I've found online).

  ```bat
  Msiexec /i "TortoiseSVN.msi" /LP "Install.log"
  ```

Comment: Thank you for looking into this aftter such a long time. I tried with to versions. The results were `TortoiseSVN 1.9.4.27285 (64 bit) Setup failed.` and `TortoiseSVN 1.13.1.28686 (64 bit) Setup failed.`

Comment: ADDLOCAL="...,**CLI**,..." is the key. Without "CLI" you don't get the command-line tools installed (i.e. svn.exe, TortoiseProc.exe).